# How does Cody understand Bumblebee in Rescue Bots?

Tags: transformers, transformers-rescue-bots

How is Cody Burns able to understand Bumblebee when the rest of his family is not able to? Has it been mentioned anywhere, such as in the books?

Comment: Heavily related, but not a dupe; [How can Raf understand Bumblebee?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53215/how-can-raf-understand-bumblebee)